# Manga with a bat winged and horned boy chosen to pose as a prince

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a few years ago. It was read left to right, and was in English. I remember it being fairly entertaining and I’d love to find it!

All I remember is that there were two nations, one with angel-looking people and the other with demon/dragon-looking people. The main character looked like the prince who had gone missing so he was chosen to act like the prince so the kingdom didn’t freak out or something. Also, I remember there being a gigantic magical pink cat who also had horns.

Comment: Hi there! I see you added the `anime` tag - was the manga also made as an anime?

Comment: Did you read this in print, or online? Is there a chance that it's a manga-style comic which is not Japanese in origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **[Pandemonium](http://www.chriswooding.com/the-books/pandemonium/)** by Chris Wooding and Cassandra Diaz; a fun romp that unfortunately doesn't seem to have the sequel it deserves (the main conflict remains unresolved at the end iof this book). It's not a manga, but the art is very manga-inspired.

The boy Seifer is the captain of the local Skullball team in a small town far from the capital. He is abducted to stand in for the missing crown prince of the demon empire, Prince Talon Pandemonium. Everybody is fooled except Talon's giant demon cat who tries to swallow Seifer every time they meet.

The beginning of the book can be read on [Google Books](https://books.google.dk/books/about/Pandemonium.html?id=wZq7Eu9Xq50C&redir_esc=y).

[image]